# Divisioning of results of two select SQL-statements

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So this is my problem:

I have 2 different sql select queries, which both return me a value (1425000 and 2850000)
What i want to do now is the following:

```
Select (query1 / query 2)
from xxxxx
where xxxx;
```

But query 1 and query 2 are quiet complicated queries, having count and sum functions in it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Average of x and y is not x/y. Mistake?

Comment: You dont need `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses if your select is fully based on subselects which have `FROM` and `WHERE` defined inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Views for things like this.

```
create view vResult1 as
select your(
         complicated(
           query(
             here()
           )
         )
       );

create view vResult2 as
select another(
         complicated(
           query(
             here()
           )
         )
       );
```

Then you may run them:

```
select vResult1/vResult2;
```

If you need parameters for your complicated queries - you may use [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure).

Comment: Your welcome. You may face a problem with filtering data for these queries - then you should use Stored Procedures, that allow to pass parameters for queries.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @q1 int, @q2 int

select @q1 = (query1)
select @q2 = (query2)

select @q1 / @q2
```

Comment: Additional information: query1 and query2 (subqueries) must have only 1 field in result.

Comment: +1 yes, you right, but I think it's what these queries do already, I can be wrong though

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.val / t2.val
FROM   (SELECT val
        FROM   foo) t1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT val
                   FROM   bar) t2
```

`(SELECT val FROM foo)` and `(SELECT val FROM bar)` can be replaced with arbitrary `SELECT` statements.

See [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/018c6/13) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use variables.. if you don't want to write it all in a single query.

```
SET @query1_result = (Select ... complicated query 1)
SET @query2_result = (Select ... complicated query 2)

Select @query1_result / @query2_result
```